# Why can't an app have direct posting permission to it's app page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, access-token

I am writing an app which is basically a service that posts media release news to various social networks including Facebook. I understand the usage of app tokens vs. user tokens vs. page tokens through the Graph API, but what I don't understand is why it requires a user token for an app to post to the app's page. User administrators will change over the lifetime of an app, it makes far more sense that an app would automatically have the necessary permissions to post to its own page's wall. This would also cut down on all the handshaking through the Graph API that seems to be required to get things done.

So, in short, why do Facebook App not have direct posting permission to their App Pages?

Answer (score 0):

Because *every* post has a user associated with it – the user who created the post.

Comment: That's just silly to me. I would have gone a step further and made users, apps, and pages all entities, and have entities post to a wall, and require permissions, and have identities, etc. It would also give them room to add new types as well. But that's just me.

Comment: And yet it's an existing decision that Facebook made – not you or me – so there are implications as a result. It's rather pointless to debate those decisions.